# Spring Cloud Stream w/Kafka + Confluent Schema Registry Client broken?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform

Curious if anyone has got this working as I'm currently struggling.

I have created simple Source and Sink applications to send and receive an Avro schema based message. The schema for the message is held in a Confluent Schema Registry. Both apps are configured to use the ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient class but I *think* there might be a bug in here somewhere. Here's what I see that makes me wonder.

If I interact with the Confluent registry's REST API I can see that there is only one version of the schema in question (lightly edited to obscure what I'm working on):

```
$ curl -i "http://schemaregistry:8081/subjects/somesubject/versions"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 05 May 2017 16:13:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json
Content-Length: 3
Server: Jetty(9.2.12.v20150709)

[1]
```

When the Source app sends off its message over Kafka I noticed that the version in the header looked a bit funky:

```
contentType"application/octet-stream"originalContentType/"application/vnd.somesubject.v845+avro"
```

I'm not 100% clear about why the `application/vnd.somesubject.v845+avro` content type is wrapped up in `application/octet-stream` but ignoring that, note that it is saying version 845 not version 1.

Looking at the `ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient` implementation I see that it `POST`s to `/subjects/(string: subject)/versions` and returns the *id* of the schema not the version. This then gets put into `SchemaReference`'s `version` field: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-schema/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/schema/client/ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient.java#L81

When the Sink app tries to fetch the schema for the message based upon the header it fails because it tries to fetch version 845 that its plucked out of the header: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-schema/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/schema/client/ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient.java#L87

Anyone have thoughts on this? Thanks in advance.

** UPDATE **

OK pretty convinced this is a bug. Took the `ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient` and modified the `register` method slightly to `POST` to `/subjects/(string: subject)` (i.e. dropped the trailing `/versions`) which per Confluent REST API docs returns a payload with the `version` in it. Works like a charm:

```
public SchemaRegistrationResponse register(String subject, String format, String schema) {
    Assert.isTrue("avro".equals(format), "Only Avro is supported");
    String path = String.format("/subjects/%s", subject);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.put("Accept",
            Arrays.asList("application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json", "application/vnd.schemaregistry+json",
                    "application/json"));
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    Integer version = null;
    try {
        String payload = this.mapper.writeValueAsString(Collections.singletonMap("schema", schema));
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(payload, headers);
        ResponseEntity<Map> response = this.template.exchange(this.endpoint + path, HttpMethod.POST, request,
                Map.class);
        version = (Integer) response.getBody().get("version");
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SchemaRegistrationResponse schemaRegistrationResponse = new SchemaRegistrationResponse();
    schemaRegistrationResponse.setId(version);
    schemaRegistrationResponse.setSchemaReference(new SchemaReference(subject, version, "avro"));
    return schemaRegistrationResponse;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Would you like to contribute with your suggestions as a PR here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pulls. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing, my pleasure @IlayaperumalGopinathan

Comment: Guys, how up2date is this implementation?

I've checked the api documentation and tested it by my own. But this implementation doesn't work with 3.3.0

Please check the documentation.
http://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/api.html

Comment: I see that it is correct in v1.3.0.M2 but not in v2.0.0.M1.

Would be nice if this fix will be in v2.0.x as well.

Comment: I'm actually no longer sure the fix I came up with is 100% right, but life has got in the way of me really getting to the bottom of things. It'd be easy to splice in what I did probably to your own project but test carefully.